# Share data with all views, best practises

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I use AppServiceProvider to get all categories on my page.

```php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register() {}

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->creator('layouts.app', function($view) {

            //Categories cache
            $categories = Cache::rememberForever('categories', function () {
                return Category::where("parent_id", "=", null)->with('subcategory.subcategory')->get();
            });
            view()->share('categories', $categories);
            
        });
    }
}
```

The data is accessible on the master layouts.app view, but not in the view it includes.
So in my layouts/app.blade.php i have this: `@yield('content')`
sadly the variable `$categories` isn't present in that content which is included. How can i change it?

The error: `Undefined variable: categories` <- but only on pages that use that variable, it is accessible on app.blade.php where i display the categories, but not in the view it includes

I tried:

```php
@yield('content', ['categories' => $categories])
```

but it gives error `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `view()->creator('layouts.app')`, every variable you share within that callback, will be shared only with `layouts.app` view and any views that `layouts.app` includes.

If you use `@extends`, for example, a new view called `example.blade.php` extends the `layouts.app` using `@extends('layouts.app'), the` categories`variable will not be accessible in`extends.blade.php`view, since you said to laravel to share that variable only with`layouts.app`via`view()->creator()` method.

The `@yield` directive is used to display the content of a given section.

Example:
My `inc.test` view has this content:

```html
<br>
view `test` included.
<br>
@section('post')
Post id:    {{ $post->id }} test
@endsection
```

My `welcome.blade.php` view, which includes `inc.test` and yields the `post` section, has this content:

```html
This is the welcome view.
<br>
It has a `post` variable shared via AppServiceProvider.
<br>
<br>
<br>
Here i'm including 'inc.test' view and yielding the post section from that view:
<br>
<br>
@include('inc.test')

@yield('post')
```

Since i shared the `post` variable with the `welcome` view via service provider, it will be available for all view included by `welcome`.

```php
view()->creator('welcome', function($view) {
    view()->share('post', Post::first());
});
```

This is the result in my browser:

[image]

Comment: ok you included that inc.test but can you access post in @yield('post') ?

Comment: Yeah, the `@section('post')` wont show until i use `@yield` directive. The Post id: 1 test comes from that yield.

Comment: @PHPisMyPassion can you add your views to the question? Maybe it helps to understand what is happening.